# UIPageViewController used to slide from view to view flickers when swiping too fast

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, sliding

As the title suggests, I'am using a UIPageViewController to swipe from view to view. I have a container view behind all three views that I'm swiping back and forth from. When I swipe too fast, a fast flicker appears showing a white background color . I was wondering if this was common among pageViewControllers in swiping and sliding. If so are there ways to fix it, otherwise, what's a better alternative for swiping and sliding between pages.

Comment: No, its not common in UIPageViewController, try giving views background color as clear color and container background color different from clear color and see if still it is flickering, will need more information from you about views creation to arrive at exact solution.